# Cómo definir un autoincrement desde un valor dado?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Cómo hago para hacer auto increment que empiece desde 200?

```
CREATE TABLE PERSONA
(
    IDPER INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    DNIPER CHAR(8),
    NOMPER VARCHAR(80),
    APEPER VARCHAR(80),
    EMAPER VARCHAR(80),
    CELPER CHAR(9),
    TIPPER CHAR(1),
    ESTPER CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'A',
    FECNACPER DATE,
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (IDPER)
);
```

Comment: [`mysql> ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 200;`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la definición de la tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE PERSONA
(
    IDPER INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    DNIPER CHAR(8),
    NOMPER VARCHAR(80),
    APEPER VARCHAR(80),
    EMAPER VARCHAR(80),
    CELPER CHAR(9),
    TIPPER CHAR(1),
    ESTPER CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'A',
    FECNACPER DATE,
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (IDPER)
) AUTO_INCREMENT = 200;
```

Comment: GRACIAS MAN FUNCIONO

Comment: @ROBERTOCARLOSSANCHEZRAMOS súper! Recuerda marcarla como aceptada si te resolvió el problema

Comment: ahyaya ya lo hice ntp bro